# Unble to copy using zclip

Tags: javascript, zclip

http://jsfiddle.net/constillations/nz6GS/1/  zclip does not copy anything in this fiddle. What mistake I am making ? Here  is the JS 
`

```
var copyText="this is a text";
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#copyBotton").zclip({
        path:"http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf",
        copy:function(){return copyText}            
    })
})
```

`

Comment: Please attempt to reproduce and summarize your problem here, not in the fiddle.

Comment: `zeroClipboard.swf` does not exist on jsFiddle. Neither does the `zclip` plugin, and you haven't even included jQuery.

Comment: swf added in fiddle. Still the result is same.

Comment: jQuery is still not included, and neither is the plugin.

Comment: Its a long code. Plz show me how can I add css html and js on stackoverflow.

Comment: can some one edit the fiddle. I wish I were good at JSfiddle. I did try the code in an editor , however the results is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Here is the reason why zclip didnt work for me : zclip works only on a page which is loaded from a server i.e the URL address should start from http or https. I was trying to execute zclip from a local file. (i didnt try zclip using local server, may be it works there). Documentation for this behavior is [here](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/).